# OMNET++ how to access function or variables in another class

Tags: omnet++, inet

I have modified inet NodeStatus.cc with a customized function that return the variable value as follows:

```
 int NodeStatus::getValueA()
 {
return ValueA;
 }
```

Then, I created another simple module called simpleNodeB.cc and I wanted to retrieve ValueA from NodeStatus.cc. I tried the following code in simpleNodeB.cc but didn't work:

```
 if(getParentModule()->getSubModule(NodeStatus).getValueA()==test1)
                        bubble("Value is the same");
```

The error message I got -> error: expected expected primary-expression before ')' token. I'm not sure if I used the correct way to call getValueA() function. Please enlighten me. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many errors in your code.

1. The method `getSubmodule` requires [a name of module](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/api/classomnetpp_1_1cModule.html#affd762a971a066ee031c98c709369ba8), not a name of class. Look at your `NED` file and check the actual name of this module.
2. `getSubmodule` returns a pointer to the `cModule` object. It has to be manually cast into another class.

Assuming that an `NodeStatus` module in your `NED` is named `fooStatus` the correct code should look like:

```
cModule *mod = getParentModule()->getSubmodule("fooStatus");
NodeStatus *status = check_and_cast<NodeStatus*>(mod);
if(status->getValueA() == test1) 
    bubble("Value is the same");
```

Reference: [OMNeT++ Manual](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/#sec:simple-modules:direct-method-calls).